# Symfony 2 - Entity is not updated

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working with form aimed at uploading the file and updating the database in Symfony2. I want to manually set value of book_id field and not to allow user to change it in the form. Thus in my controller before using doctrine to persist document I am calling:

```
$documents->setBookId('1');
```

Unluckilly I get error which indicates that the doctrine does not recognise the above hard coded value input.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Documents (book_id, marker, document_date, link, notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "fdd", "2015-04-04", null, "test"]:
```

To my mind this may be connected with the fact that book_id field is related to Books. Therefore probably I should use setBook function instead. Could you please advice how to do this properly?

My controler file looks like this:

```
/**
* This code is aimed at checking if the book is chosen and therefore whether any further works may be carried out
*/
$session = new Session();
if(!$session->get("App_Books_Chosen_Lp")) return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('app_listbooks'));
// Authorization goes here 

$documents = new Documents();
$form = $this->createForm(new DocumentsType(), $documents);
$form->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Dodaj dokument'));
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $documents->upload();
    $documents->setBookId('1');
    $em->persist($documents);
    $em->flush();

}
return $this->render('AppBundle:Documents:adddocuments.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

Document class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Documents")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */

class Documents
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Books", inversedBy="documents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $book;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $book_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=220)
     */
    protected $marker;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", length=220)
     */
    protected $document_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=220)
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
     protected $link;

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
     protected $notes;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set book_id
     *
     * @param integer $bookId
     * @return Documents
     */
    public function setBookId($bookId)
    {
        $this->book_id = $bookId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get book_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getBookId()
    {
        return $this->book_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set marker
     *
     * @param string $marker
     * @return Documents
     */
    public function setMarker($marker)
    {
        $this->marker = $marker;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get marker
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMarker()
    {
        return $this->marker;
    }

    /**
     * Set document_date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $documentDate
     * @return Documents
     */
    public function setDocumentDate($documentDate)
    {
        $this->document_date = $documentDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get document_date
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDocumentDate()
    {
        return $this->document_date;
    }

    /**
     * Set link
     *
     * @param string $link
     * @return Documents
     */
    public function setLink($link)
    {
        $this->link = $link;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get link
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLink()
    {
        return $this->link;
    }


    /**
     * Set notes
     *
     * @param string $notes
     * @return Documents
     */
    public function setNotes($notes)
    {
        $this->notes = $notes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get notes
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNotes()
    {
        return $this->notes;
    }

    /**
     * Set book
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Books $book
     * @return Documents
     */
    public function setBook(\AppBundle\Entity\Books $book = null)
    {
        $this->book = $book;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get book
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Books 
     */
    public function getBook()
    {
        return $this->book;
    }

    /*
    * ### FILE UPLOAD PROCESS ### 
    */

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

      public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/documents';
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // use the original file name here but you should
        // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

        // move takes the target directory and then the
        // target filename to move to
        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
        );

        // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
        $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

        // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
        $this->file = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first since you're using `ManyToOne` relation, you don't actually need another property refering to the book - `book_id`. You can remove that and leave `book` only.

Then in your controller you have to query the database for that `Book` and set the that object your `Document`.

You can do it like this:

```
$bookId = 1; // Following your example, let's say tou already know the book ID.
$book = $em->getReference('AppBundle:Books', $bookId);

// Check if we actually found a record and then set it to Documents
// Looking at your entity mapping, your reference to Book can not be null,
// but doing an extra check never hurts, since this is just an example.
if( $book ) {
    $documents->setBook($book);
}
```

#### -Update-

If you want to directly insert the bookID, then what is the purpose of having `ManyToOne` reference in your entity? Eventually you're going to have to start using doctrine's relations and objects properly. Also, the cool thing about `getReference` method is that you are getting a reference to an entity, without having to load the entity from the database - you get the so called `Proxy objects`.

> The method EntityManager#getReference($entityName, $identifier) lets you obtain a reference to an entity for which the identifier is known, without loading that entity from the database. This is useful, for example, as a performance enhancement, when you want to establish an association to an entity for which you have the identifier

You can read further about this [here.](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html)

Comment: But am I not in this way generating unnecessary query to database? I am asking this as If I would make this relation manually (using SQL queries only) I could just simply input bookID in this field and this would save me one query.

Comment: @Abdel5 I've added a bit more information about this.

Comment: Thanks everything is clear for me now. Thanks for providing me with doc link that is always helpful.  The code above was a bit simplified. I will be using $session->get("App_Books_Chosen_Lp") as value of "book_id" so the value will in fact vary. This is the reason for ManyToOne relationship.